# Laravel: How to show form after submission?

Tags: php, laravel, web

I am new to Laravel and currently working on a project where the guests enter form data for booking a room in a hotel and after submitting it, they will be redirected to a page showing their booking they have just done. I know this can be done by allowing guests to create login account but my project requires login only for the backend(admin). (Q2.)Also the guests can view booking by entering the booking ID and their last name.

My controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
   {
      $book = new book();
      $book->title = $request->input('title');
      $book->fname = $request->input('firstname');
      $book->lname = $request->input('lastname');
      $book->country = $request->input('country');
      $book->phone = $request->input('phone');
      $book->email = $request->input('email');
       $book->no_rooms = $request->input('no_rooms');
       $book->room_type_id = $request->input('type_room');
       $book->no_adults = $request->input('adults');
       $book->no_children = $request->input('children');
       $book->meal_id = $request->input('meal');
       $book->check_in = $request->input('check_in');
       $book->check_out = $request->input('check_out');
       $book->save();
   }
   public function show(book $book)
{

   return view('book.show', compact('book'));
}
```

The way I want it to display after it has been submitted:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-6">
<table class="table table-striped text-dark">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> Name: </td>
<td> {{$book->title}} &nbsp; {{$book->firstname}} &nbsp; {{$book->lastname}}    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Phone </td>
<td> {{$book->phone}}     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Email </td>
<td> {{$book->email}}     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Phone </td>
<td> {{$book->phone}}     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Passport Issued: </td>
<td> {{$book->country}}     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Number of rooms: </td>
<td> {{$book->no_rooms}}     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Room Type </td>
<td> {{$book->type_room}}     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> No of adults: </td>
<td> {{$book->adults}}     </td>
</tr><tr>
<td> No of children: </td>
<td> {{$book->children}}     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Meal plan: </td>
<td> {{$book->meals_id}}     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Check-in: </td>
<td> {{$book->check_in}}     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Check-out: </td>
<td> {{$book->check_out}}     </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `book` class name correct (i.e. lower case "b")?

Comment: @Tpojka yes, it is in lower case. `class book extends Model`

Comment: You should stick with [this naming convention](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices) which will help you avoid 80% of unforced errors. Nevertheless have you checked is data unavailable in controller? Instead of returning view, put dd($booking) in show method and check what is available there.

Comment: @Tpojka yes you are right, even when I created dummy projects I followed it but now for some reason it slipped my mind. Someone else has helped me with it by using flash() and old variable. But now I am struggling with displaying the guest his/her reservation based on booking reference and last name

Comment: Show route for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your situation, you wish to show the same data introduced by the user after form submission.

I can think that redirecting to a page that show your div without anything else, is not enough. You'll still need to access to data entered in the form. 
Laravel store form data in a session variable called old, according to documentation, that variable should be available during next request after submission, so you could try to get data using

```
<table class="table table-striped text-dark">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> Name: </td>
            <td> {{ old('title') }} &nbsp; {{ old('firstname') }} &nbsp; {{ old('lastname') }}    </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Phone </td>
            <td> {{ old('phone') }}     </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Email </td>
            <td> {{ old('email') }}     </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Phone </td>
            <td> {{ old('phone') }}     </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Passport Issued: </td>
            <td> {{ old('country') }}     </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Number of rooms: </td>
            <td> {{ old('no_rooms') }}     </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Room Type </td>
            <td> {{ old('type_room') }}     </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> No of adults: </td>
            <td> {{ old('adults') }}     </td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td> No of children: </td>
            <td> {{ old('children') }}     </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Meal plan: </td>
            <td> {{ old('meals_id') }}     </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Check-in: </td>
            <td> {{ old('check_in') }}     </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Check-out: </td>
            <td> {{ old('check_out') }}     </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Just in case that you don't have old data available in your session because a successive redirect, you should inject that data in your session using flash.
You can find more detailed information [here, in laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests#old-input)

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for! But I was thinking to use the same show.blade.php file to display the output when the guest tries to view the booking, i.e., he enters the booking reference number and then let say his/her last name to view the booking (show.blade)

Comment: Hi Faizan, so I just misunderstand your needs! If your user must enter his reservation reference number, you just have to make a database request and then show its results to the user, it is not at the moment after submitting the original form, in fact it could be at any moment.

Comment: Are you able to create the new form and make the necessary request to your database in order to get the information needed?

Comment: No you actually understood both of my questions, you helped me with the first one! The later you are telling me I am yet to do it, the logic I will be implementing is, to get the user reference number and last name (for example) make a request to DB to check if it exists or not, if yes then display it to them or else just display it does not exist. Thank you so much for your help really!

Comment: My pleasure Faizan, glad to help in any way. If you need further assistance just send me a message. Regards.

Comment: Thank you really, I am having an issue while displaying. I have two tables, bookings and room_types, the bookings table has a column room_type_id that is a foreign key to room_types.id and I want to display the type of room instead of id. {{$book->room_type_id->room_types->type}} but it is not working, it is a foreign key and called in model also. (type is a column in room_types that contains the type of the room)

Comment: Hi Faizan, I guess in your model you have relationships defined, if a reservation only applies to a single room_type you should use belongsTo but if a user can make a booking for several room_types in the same reservation the relationships is belongsToMany. So in your controller you will be able to call relationship as booking->room_type->type (more information https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)

Comment: Thank you, I used MySQL query even tho my models and relationships were fine and I re read the documentation multiple times. I am done with that part but as you suggested to use `$request->flash()` and then `<tr>
            <td> Room Type </td>
            <td> {{ old('type_room') }}     </td>
        </tr>` this is returning the ID and not the type of room, is there anyway to solve this? I tried using the same query but since it is old('type_room') and not $book->room_type_id it is not working.. (if not possible no worries, I even tried using flashExcept on it and then changed no use)

Comment: Ok, so here the point should be, how the user select room_type, because you must mimic the original control. eg: if it is a select with values of room_type.id and labels from room_type table, you should replicate that select and compare option value with id from old input.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect to the show method from the bottom of your store method:

```
// Replace MyController with the name of your controller
return redirect()->action(
    'MyController@show', ['book' => $book]
);
```

For more information check out the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/master/redirects#redirecting-controller-actions

Comment: I have tried this and it does redirect the page but it does not display the information, that's the issue I am facing at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use the laravel helper **redirect()**

```
return redirect()->route('route name here');
```

or

```
return redirect('your-form-path');
```

read more here: [laravel http redirects](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/redirects)

Comment: I have tried this and it does redirect the page but it does not display the information, that's the issue I am facing at the moment.

Comment: @Faizan Are you putting `redirect` in `store` method after saving?

Comment: @Tpojka yes, I am putting it this in store method after saving it. It redirects to the show.blade.php but does not display anything from the form submitted..

Comment: Unfortunately I understood your question incorrectly. In this case, the solution uses the old helper to retrieve the data and place it inside the value="" as Farid Silva wrote.